# Indenting paragraphs in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, documents, indentation

I would like to format a Microsoft Word document such that the first line of every paragraph is indented, with the exception of the first paragraph in a section which would not be indented. How can I do this?

Comment: This is one of the standard ways of doing paragraph indentation in Swedish. Too bad Microsoft Word hasn't any support for it. This is one of many cases where HTML+CSS is superior (p + p).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use two styles for this. For example you could change the "standard" style adding an indentation for the first line as [described in the Microsoft Office Online help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP100165281033.aspx#1). Basically you'll have to go in *"Indents and Spacing"* and under "*Indentation*" click "*First line*" from the Special list. In the "*By*" box, set the amount of indentation.

Then, create a new style a name it "Paragraph1" for example. Remove the indentation from this style and apply it to every *first* paragraph of each section.

Comment: In that last sentence, do you mean "and apply it to the _first_ paragraph of each section"?

Comment: If applying this to a new document, do as splattne suggests, then for Paragraph1, set the "Style for following paragraph" to be Normal (or whatever the standard style is). That way, you only have to set the style for the first paragraph, and after you hit Return, the style for the next and subsequent paragraphs will automatically be Normal.